Copy a symfony project from a laptop to another
I have a symfony project which I have under my Laragon www folder. I would like to copy it to be used by my colleague on his laptop.
When we simply copy/paste of the folder to his local, it does not work properly (css files are not recognized...). Is there a way to properly set it up without using git?

Do you copy with cache folder? If so - clear cache first.

I did clear the cache folder but nothing changed.

So than describe what you mean by css files are not recognized. Wrong paths or something?

I think you have a problem with the link. I think you are using relative import. It's better to use absolute import for each link.
So, if you import a file like this:
<img href="{{ asset("file.jpg") }} />

Change it to:
<img href="{{ absolute_url(asset("file.jpg")) }} />

To test in a local environment, you can forget Laragon and simply use the Symfony binary.
Install it and run the command :
symfony serve

